# Using Angular CLI's 'new' and 'build' results in stuck on "Loading..."

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Created a new project with `ng new test` and ran `ng build --prod`. Then pushed the dist folder into a Github repo and enabled pages. The resulting page seems to be stuck on "Loading....". Also recreated this using express to sendFile the index.html in dist and again the Angular2 app is stuck on "Loading..."

`ng serve` seems to be working fine and localhost:4200 results in "app works!" displaying.

Is this a known bug and if so, how else can this project be built for production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set base href while generating the dist folder.

try something like this

```
ng build --prod --base-href .
```

P.S : Don't forget the dot at the end.Then push it.

For express to serve the dist folder,
please follow the following gist
[gist.github.com/parthghiya/eb337e2ee63ce8785d714e251b7ef0b8](http://gist.github.com/parthghiya/eb337e2ee63ce8785d714e251b7ef0b8)

Comment: That works for pages! But won't work with Express and still get the stuck on loading. Just doing sendFile('/path/dist/index.html') This might be a separate issue. Any ideas?

Comment: need to look at main.js [your express file] code. here is one of sample GIST https://gist.github.com/parthghiya/eb337e2ee63ce8785d714e251b7ef0b8.
What error's you are getting when u do developer console ?

Comment: Sorry and thank you I'm very new to web dev! I ended up figuring it out and just in case someone else has this issue, I had to set the mount path to serve static pages: `const path = require('path');`  and `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));`.

Comment: @Biiiiiird : My pleasure, i will update the answer. you can +1  it, glad it helped.